# What is the opposite of topmost in GTK+?

Tags: gtk

In WindowsForms there is a property called TopMost that when True makes the window always in front of anything else in the desktop (like dialog messages). I'd to know if there is a opposite property in GTK+, in that when activated would make the window stay in the back of every thing on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a line between the window manager's capabilities and what a UI toolkit can do. The toolkit takes care of the window's content, the window manager determines the placement and layering of windows. *Such property is likely to be non-existent*. It is potentially not feasible to implement the desired property across platforms (WMs) in a meaningful way.
Furthermore [`Gtk.WindowType`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/gtk3-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkWindowType) only suggests only `POPUP` and `TOPLEVEL`.
Are you looking for a [`Gtk.StatusIcon`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/GtkStatusIcon.html) for selectively showing and hiding your application window?

Comment: About the last question on you answer: I was actually looking for a way to let the window behind of everything (window), but as you said it's not possible, the only application I know that own this feature is [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I know Conky as well and instantly thought of it. I tried to figure out how Conky does it, according to the WP article "[...]  Conky is drawn directly in an X window". Probably some X API is in use, I encourage you to read the source or ask the devs.